# How do I apply style to the headertext property of a detailsview TemplateField?

Tags: css, asp.net, detailsview

I have a detailsview with a TemplateField:

```html
                <Fields>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Band">                        
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("bandname") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Fields>
```

How would I apply a style to just the HeaderText, as I wish to make it bold?

Comment: CSS doesn't care what particular framework/IDE/language/technology you use to create your `HTML`. As long as you have a stylesheet that loads in your page and you write valid code, it will apply to your DOM. Show me the outcome of that syntax and I'll show you the CSS. I assure you it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by adding a `<HeaderStyle />` child to your `TemplateField`.

> The HeaderStyle property governs the appearance of any text displayed in the header item of a type derived from DataControlField.

There you can define the styles inline or specify a `CssClass` if you have the styles defined elsewhere.

```html
<Fields>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Band">
    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="true" CssClass="myheaderclass" />
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("bandname") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
</Fields>
```

Read more: [DataControlField.HeaderStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfield.headerstyle.aspx)